# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

i cant figure out what is the problem

```
div#wrapper(ng-app="adminApp")
....
```

js/

```
var adminApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ui-router']);
```

if i use

```
var adminApp = angular.module('adminApp', []);
```

the error disappear

why is that?

UPDATE:

adding image from console

[image]

Comment: if you using ui-router, have you loaded ui-router.js file on your html page?

Comment: yes ofcourse im pretty sure

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/y3YSGiw2OWai1kaTv6KB

Comment: You forgot loading angular.js file to your html.

Comment: i didnt forgot angular

Answer (score 24, accepted):

the module name is `ui-router` but you need to inject `ui.router` and not `ui-router`

```
var adminApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ui.router']);
```

check out [PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/4y8x8jyd1ano1X9T1OFx?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! This comment saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

It's a little late, but maybe it will save someone's time. In my case I've mixed up links: instead of `angular-ui-router.min.js` I've downloaded `angular-route.min.js`. Obviously angular-ui-router is necessary for this.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar issue and in addition to following the steps outline above by "entre", I had to make sure the angularjs script tag comes before the ui-router tag as such:

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The reverse order will also cause an $injector:modulerr